# Can we use resttemplate for consuming where the api is using jersey to produce

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, resttemplate

We are migrating our applications to Spring boot. One API is consuming the other API. The producing API is using jersey to produce the service. Can we use resttemplate for consuming the old API which is using jersey

Comment: Show the code you want to migrate

Comment: As long as the APIs are interacting with each other using REST URL and JSON/XML then you can use RestTemplate to invoke your old API like any other REST API.